# "Not ... Is Nothing" versus "... IsNot Nothing"

Tags: vb.net

Does anyone here use VB.NET and have a strong preference for or against using `Not foo Is Nothing` as opposed to `foo IsNot Nothing`? If so, why?

For Example

```
If var1 IsNot Nothing Then
...
End If
```

and

```
If Not var1 Is Nothing Then
...
End If
```

I just want to know which one is better?
Are they both equally acceptable?

Comment: I've already looked this Question.[It](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5791/507860) is a Comparism of IsNothing(obj) Between obj Is Nothing.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The

```
If Not var1 Is Nothing Then
```

Is a hangover from VB6.  There didn't used to be an IsNot, and so this was the only way to determine if a variable was not `Nothing`.  It seems to be redundant in VB.NET.

Comment: `IsNot` is a newer operator that didn't exist in pre .NET2 versions.

Comment: I wonder if it's actually faster or compiles to the same. I mean, `Not x Is Nothing` first does a check for type equality, then negates it. `x IsNot Nothing` does only a check for type unequality which the runtime might be capable of doing faster (dumbly imaginable as if it checks a type field by field and can leave by the first non-matching one rather than going through each field to check for equality - on top just to negate the result eventually).

Answer (score 17):

`foo IsNot Nothing`

The following line is straight from Microsoft's [Visual Basic Coding Conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h63fsef3.aspx):

> Use the `IsNot` keyword instead of `Not`...Is Nothing.

Answer (score 7):

I would go with the first variant - it reads like English and is easier to follow/understand than the second one. Other than that, they are equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

I found a similar question here [VB.NET - IsNothing versus Is Nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5791/vb-net-isnothing-versus-is-nothing), where I feel this question was exhaustively answered. Among the answers Jack Snipes identified http://weblogs.asp.net/psteele/410336, a blog that gives some extra detail. From those I prefer and have used

```
IsNot Nothing
```

which also makes my code easier to read and understand.

Comment: "Not...Is Nothing" is not the same thing as "Not IsNothing(...)" Not outright wrong, but not an answer for this question.

Answer (score -1):

Using VB 7.0

`If var1 Is Not Nothing Then`

generates an "invalid use of object error" as per this ["VBForums"](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?509805-RESOLVED-correct-usage-of-quot-Is-Not-Nothing-quot) link.

`If var1 IsNot Nothing Then`

generates a "Compile error:  Expected: Then or GoTo"

`If Not IsNothing(var1) Then`

worked like a champ

Comment: "`If var1 IsNot Nothing Then` generates a Compile error" of course it does, when there is no statement or block afterwards. `var1 IsNot Nothing` itself will work. You also fail to show what `Not var1 Is Nothing` does, so you don't really answer the question. And please fix your formatting