# How to check dictionary is null in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, dictionary

Am new to vb.net and doing a work flow in vb.net, i need to check whether a dictionary is null. I have declared a dictionary, but have not assigned any value to it.

When i use `IsNothing()` method it gives object reference exception. How can i check?

```
Dim CustDicAs New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
CustDic.IsNothing()
```

Comment: show the code where it goes wrong

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5791/11683

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You check variables for `Nothing` with `Not Is Nothing` or `IsNot Nothing` or via the old [`IsNothing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5adx7fxz%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) function from Visual Basic.

```
Dim dict As Dictionary(Of String, String)
```

1. Not Is Nothing

   ```
   If Not dict Is Nothing Then
     ' not nothing 
   End If
   ```
2. IsNot Nothing

   ```
   If dict IsNot Nothing Then
     ' not nothing 
   End If
   ```
3. [IsNothing function(](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5adx7fxz(v=vs.90).aspx)VB)

   ```
   If Not IsNothing(dict) Then
     ' not nothing 
   End If
   ```

I wouldn't use the VB6 function `IsNothing`  in .NET anymore since it introduces unneeded dependencies and  for the reason mentioned [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/psteele/410336) (it allows value types and always returns `False`).

Comment: If Not does not appear in Workflow foundation dotnet 4.5

Comment: @Sajeetharan: `Not` is the logical negation operator and it's available since VB.NET 1.0.