# SSRS 2008 Is Nothing vs = Nothing

Tags: reporting-services, null, ssrs-2008

When writing an expression in SSRS 2008 to check for blank values (NULL), is there any difference between Fields!FieldName.Value = Nothing and Fields!FieldName.Value Is Nothing?  It seems that i have seen it both ways. I am currently using = Nothing and it seems to be working.

Comment: possible duplicate of [VB.NET - IsNothing versus Is Nothing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5791/vb-net-isnothing-versus-is-nothing)

Answer (score 1):

answered here in many ways:  [VB.NET - IsNothing versus Is Nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5791/vb-net-isnothing-versus-is-nothing)

In short, one is a function call and one is straight evaluation.