How to close a form on mouseLeave
I want to create a custom picturebox in which picture is zoomed in a dedicated form on mouse hover.
Everything works fine except the fact that the user must clic out the zoomed image to close it altough i want to close it on mouse leave?
Here's my code:
Public Class CtrlNoticePictureBox
    Inherits PictureBox
    Private frmPicExtended As New Form
    Public Sub New()
        AddHandler Me.MouseEnter, New System.EventHandler(AddressOf Me.PictureBox_MouseEnter)
        AddHandler Me.MouseLeave, New System.EventHandler(AddressOf Me.PictureBox_MouseLeave)
    End Sub
    Private Sub PictureBox_MouseEnter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Dim screenCurrent As Screen = Screen.FromControl(Me)
        Dim workingArea As Rectangle = screenCurrent.WorkingArea
        Dim locationForm As Point = Me.TopLevelControl.Location

        frmPicExtended = New Form With {
            .ShowInTaskbar = False,
            .MaximizeBox = False,
            .ControlBox = False,
            .Location = New Point(Me.Width + locationForm.X, Me.Height + locationForm.Y),
            .StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual,
            .FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None
        }
        Dim picBoxExtended = New PictureBox With {
            .Name = "pictureBox",
            .Image = Me.Image,
            .SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom,
            .Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        }
        frmPicExtended.Controls.Add(picBoxExtended)
        frmPicExtended.BringToFront()
        frmPicExtended.Show()
    End Sub
    Private Sub PictureBox_MouseLeave(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Dim rectPicArea As New Rectangle With {.Location = Me.PointToScreen(Point.Empty), .Size = Me.Size}
        If IsNothing(frmPicExtended) = False Then
            If Not rectPicArea.Contains(Cursor.Position) Then
                frmPicExtended.Dispose()
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
    Function PointToCurrentScreen(ByVal self As Control, ByVal location As Point) As Point
        Dim screenBounds = Screen.FromControl(self).Bounds
        Dim globalCoordinates = self.PointToScreen(location)
        Return New Point(globalCoordinates.X - screenBounds.X, globalCoordinates.Y - screenBounds.Y)
    End Function
End Class

Here is the result:


There's no use handling the MouseLeave event of the original PictureBox. You want to close the zoom form when the user's mouse leaves the zoom form, so that's where you need to be handling the event. Don't create a vanilla Form object and construct it there. Design a dedicated form with the functionality you want, including closing itself on MouseLeave, and create an instance of that. You'll probably actually want to handle the event of the PictureBox in that form.

As an aside, the function IsNothing looks like a relic from VBScript.  Prefer to use frmPicExtended IsNot Nothing for this case.

@jmcilhinney : what is a "vanilla form"? I googled it but found nothing.

@Craig : duly noted. To complete your remark : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5791/isnothing-versus-is-nothing

To refer to something as "vanilla" is to say that it is "plain" or "basic, with nothing extra added". It comes from the mistaken idea that vanilla ice cream is plain and has nothing added while other flavours do contain something extra. It is a colloquialism that I think that most native English speakers understand, so I'm guessing that English is not your first language. My point was that you were creating a Form object and then modifying that in code when you should be adding a new form to your project with the desired extras and creating an instance of that.

If you look closely at the gif image, when the mouse moves to the greenish container, it actually leaves the internal picBoxExtended, not the CtrlNoticePictureBox instance. The covered area of the main PictureBox - by the modeless Form - does not receive the mouse inputs unless that Form and its children are transparent to the mouse inputs. As a result, the MouseLeave event does not fire and the zoom Form remains. You also need to implement the MouseLeave event of the internal PictureBox to hide the Form.
Here's a working example with some additions and modifications.
<DesignerCategory("Code")>
Public Class CtrlNoticePictureBox
    Inherits PictureBox

    Public Enum StartPosition
        Relative
        Center
        Cursor
    End Enum

    Private FrmZoom As Form
    Private PicZoom As PictureBox

    <DefaultValue(StartPosition.Center)>
    Public Property ZoomFormStartPosition As StartPosition = StartPosition.Center

    <DefaultValue(True)>
    Public Property KeepZoomFormWithinScreen As Boolean = True

    Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseEnter(e As EventArgs)
        MyBase.OnMouseEnter(e)
        If Image Is Nothing Then Return
        If FrmZoom Is Nothing Then CreateZoomForm()
        If FrmZoom.Visible Then Return
        Dim loc As Point
        Select Case ZoomFormStartPosition
            Case StartPosition.Relative
                loc = PointToScreen(Point.Empty)
            Case StartPosition.Center
                loc = PointToScreen(Point.Empty)
                loc.X += (Width - FrmZoom.Width) \ 2
                loc.Y += (Height - FrmZoom.Height) \ 2
            Case Else
                loc = Cursor.Position
        End Select
        If KeepZoomFormWithinScreen Then
            Dim sc = Screen.FromControl(Me).Bounds ' or .WorkingArea
            If loc.X + FrmZoom.Width > sc.Width Then
                loc.X = sc.Right - FrmZoom.Width
            End If
            If loc.Y + FrmZoom.Height > sc.Height Then
                loc.Y = sc.Bottom - FrmZoom.Height
            End If
            loc.X = Math.Max(0, loc.X)
            loc.Y = Math.Max(0, loc.Y)
        End If
        FrmZoom.Location = loc
        PicZoom.Image = Image
        FrmZoom.Show()
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseLeave(e As EventArgs)
        MyBase.OnMouseLeave(e)
        If Not ClientRectangle.Contains(PointToClient(Cursor.Position)) Then
            FrmZoom.Hide()
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(disposing As Boolean)
        If disposing Then
            FrmZoom?.Dispose()
        End If
        MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
    End Sub

    Private Sub CreateZoomForm()
        PicZoom = New PictureBox With {
            .SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom,
            .Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
        }
        FrmZoom = New Form With {
            .FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None,
            .ControlBox = False,
            .ShowInTaskbar = False,
            .TopMost = True,
            .StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual,
            .Size = New Size(Width * 2, Height * 2)
        }
        FrmZoom.Controls.Add(PicZoom)
        AddHandler FrmZoom.Disposed, Sub(s, e) PicZoom.Dispose()
        AddHandler PicZoom.MouseLeave, Sub(s, e) OnMouseLeave(EventArgs.Empty)
    End Sub
End Class

Notes

In a derived class, override the methods of the base class and do not subscribe to its events. Other controls can subscribe to events if needed.
No need to keep creating and destroying the zoom Form. Create it on first access and override the owner's Dispose method to dispose of it.

